# What is sw.js for workbox-webpack-plugin.InjectManifest supposed to include?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, manifest, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to use [workbox-webpack-plugin.InjectManifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#injectmanifest_plugin) and all the examples I find look something like the code below, but I can't find an example of what `src/sw.js` is supposed to look like. I tried searching for example's of service worker files and feel like I might be starting a goose chase learning way more about service workers that I need to without actually getting an example. All I'm trying to do is include my manifest settings with my service worker. I thought I would be able to do this, considering the name of the function is called InjectManifest

```
// Inside of webpack.config.js:
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // Other webpack config...
  plugins: [
    // Other plugins...
    new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './src/sw.js',
    })
  ]
};
```

---

**Manifest.js** (Extra, if it's useful)

```js
const Icon192 = require("../images/icon-192x192.png");
const Icon512 = require("../images/icon-512x512.png")

const manifest = {
  icons: [
    {
      src: Icon192,
      sizes: "192x192",
      type: "image/png",
    },
    {
      src: Icon512,
      sizes: "512x512",
      type: "image/png",
    },
  ],
  name: "My_App",
  short_name: "My_App",
  orientation: "portrait",
  display: "standalone",
  start_url: "/",
  theme_color: "    #228B22",
  background_color: "#ffffff",
  description: "Any Maskable",
  start_url: "https://example.com",
  display: "browser",
  prefer_related_applications: false
};

module.exports = JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very much depends on the functionality you'd like in your service worker. [This section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started#using_workbox) of the Workbox getting started guide walks through a few use cases, including precaching and runtime caching, and the accompanying code is what would appear in your `sw.js` file.

At its most basic, if all you're interested in is precaching all of the assets in your `webpack` build, the following could be used as your `sw.js`:

```js
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```